# Magento 2 - Category or product page return 404 sometimes for multiple store view

Tags: magento2, product, multistore

We have setup a store with multiple store view for different languages (e.g. English and French). Sometimes, when we visit the category or product page, it returns 404. But after switching to another language, say French and switching back to English again, the category or product page will show properly. Why will this happen?

Comment: Plz go to admin category and save category and goto that category parent category and save again for that and run indexer command

Comment: Is it an open issue of Magento 2?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?